# send sms from SMSPortalFragment not working

Tags: java, android, sms, send, android-fragmentactivity

I have been trying to send test messages from using `send_sms api.` My `SMSPortalFragment.java` code show no error. Also there is no other error shown in Logcat.

1. The code builds and installs in the Galaxy S8.
2. The app runs fun.
3. Going to `fragment_smsportal.xml` is working fine.
4. I can type in my name and message.
5. On button click it asks for my `PERMISSION` in runtime.
6. NO MESSAGE IS SENT EVEN AFTER I ALLOW `PERMISSION`.

**java code:**

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS =0 ;

Button sendButon;
EditText fullName;
EditText textMessage;
String phoneNo = "***********";
String name;
String message;
String sendMessage;

public SMSPortalFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View smsportal = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_smsportal, container, false);

    fullName = (EditText) smsportal.findViewById(R.id.fullName);
    textMessage = (EditText) smsportal.findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
    sendButon = (Button) smsportal.findViewById(R.id.sendButon);

    sendButon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendSMSMessage();
        }
    });

    return smsportal;
}

private void sendSMSMessage() {
    name = fullName.getText().toString();
    message = textMessage.getText().toString();
    sendMessage = name + " " + message;


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sendMessage, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SMS failed, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

PS: I removed my phone number from this code for security concern.

Answer (score 1):

> Do not write your send logic in onRequestPermissionsResult()
> and

## Try this...

> Manifest permission

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

> and here is the snippet

```
   try {
            Bundle msgDataBundle = intent.getExtras();
            String mobileNumber = msgDataBundle.getString("MobileNumber");
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            //  smsManager.sendTextMessage(mobileNumber,null,"sam",null,null);
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(mobileNumber, null, "Test Sample Message Text", null, null);
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("---", "Sent");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("---", "Fail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I have followed the codes from here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm

using SmsManager API.

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way..took me a while..being the noob I am..but it is working now..